# Просчитать расстояние до точки

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть 4 точки с их координатами, а так же есть, так скажем, коэффициенты удаления, которые определяют расстояние до 5 точки. Как определить точное расстояние от каждой из 4 точек до 5 точки?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJtBe.jpg

[image]

Comment: Вроде для 2D одна точка лишняя?

Comment: Минусить вопрос не надо. Это задача триангуляции в условиях когда расстояния известны с точностью до масштабного коэффициента. Важна для навигации в помещениях размеченных радио маячками (или на местности).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ваши уточнения, да в тело вопроса бы ;-)

Answer (score 4):

## Решение

Фиксированные точки обозначим ABCD, искомая точка X. Проведем прямые через ABCD чтоб образовался четырёхугольник. Он делит плоскость на 9 областей. Внутренний четырехугольник имеет площадь постоянную [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С каждого ребра достроим до точки X треугольники. Сумма площадей этих треугольников будет равна площади четырехугольника для центрального сектора. Для секторов за углами 2 площади с плюсом, 2 с минусом, для секторов за ребром 3 площади с плюсом - одна с минусом.

Стороны обозначим через функцию к известному коэфиценту. Если линейно, то `AX = Ka*r`, `BX = Kb*r` и т.д.

Площади треугольников выражаются по формуле Герона через неизвестную `r` и получается 9 уравнений:

```
S=S1+S2+S3+S4
S=S1+S2+S3-S4
S=S1+S2-S3-S4
..
S=-S1+S2+S3+S4
```

Одно из них будет иметь решение в котором r действительное и положительное.

Так как в тегах есть python, нужно записать эту большущую функцию и пройтись по ней численными методами.

Хотя если исключить одну точку, то уравнений останется 7.

Если кто засунет это решение в матлаб и получит r - напишите отдельный ответ - скину рейтинга ;)

Прошлые мысли:

---

Удаление считается по формуле `(x-xi)²+(y-yi)²=(ki*r)²` в случае линейного коэффициента. x,y-неизвестная точка, xi,yi - известные точки

Дальше выписывайте коэффициенты и координаты точек в систему уравнений с 3мя переменными.

Тут стоит перейти к полярным координатам и сделать замену переменной.

Для решение системы нужно 3 уравнения, найдешь x, y, r. Там получится несколько вариантов ответа. Подставив в 4ое уравнение выбираешь единственный правильный

---

Развивая идею @Qwertiy получится более простая система уравнений если попарно разделить коэффициенты.

для каждой пары точек найдем проекцию на отрезок и квадрат высоты на известное ребро.

расстояние до объекта выражается из этого и приравнивается этому же отрезку из другой пары. выходит квадратное уравнение с 2мя корнями. правильный корень выбирается по 4ой точке.

Comment: [Обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135621/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-eri).

Comment: Не могли бы пояснить, что значат переменные?

Comment: @Obii13 рисовать надо...